# Blockchain API: Wallet version 4 not supported

Tags: node.js, blockchain, blockchain.info

После обновления кошелька Blockchain до 4 версии отвалился API

https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3 
Стартую:

```
1624024372643 - info: blockchain.info wallet service v0.26.3 running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

При попытке получить новый кошелек:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/merchant/:guid/new_address
```

пишет:

```
1624024392124 - error: Wallet version 4 not supported.
```

В официальной ветке на гитхабе тишина по этому вопросу уже 2 недели. Какие могут быть решения?

Comment: Плюсую, проблема так и не решена?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается созданием нового кошелька через API.

Eсли же залогиниться в него через веб-интерфейс, то он автоматически обновится до 4 версии и снова отвалится.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это либо как комментарий, либо как правку вопроса, а не в качестве ответа. ведь ответом это не является.